# What is a HTTP header? What is a charset?

Tags: xhtml, character-encoding, http-headers

I am new to the world of coding as well as PHP and XHTML. I was just going through the details of meta tags and do not understand the property http-equiv nor what is the charset used for as well as what the value UTF-8 refers to e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good article by Joel Spolsky that discusses charsets. Take a look:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

As for HTTP headers, a quick Google search for "understanding HTTP headers" turned up quite a few good articles that describe them. Here's one: [HTTP Headers for Dummies](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/).

In short, HTTP headers are basically small messages that get sent to the user's web browser that tell the browser about the output it's going to receive (ie, is it a web page, a file, an image; should it be cached; etc), or for things like cookies that should be saved by the client's browser.

HTTP headers are also sent from the user's web browser back to the server. The most obvious example are again, cookies - every cookie that is saved by the browser is supposed to be sent back to the server on each HTTP request.

In your case, you're probably talking about a specific HTTP header that defines the character set for the page. The `<meta http-equiv="">` tags are used to simulate HTTP headers.

For example, if you had a static HTML page and wanted to take advantage of a particular HTTP header, but couldn't configure it in the web server, you could use a `<meta http-equiv="">` tag to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks Ryan. Had a quick look at article and it seems it'll take me a while to grasp the concepts. I was hoping if someone could explain it to me in the simplest of examples so that if I can understand that, I can understand the more complex concepts.

Comment: Gotcha. I added more to my answer to explain the HTTP headers part of your question, but I think you're really wondering about charsets. The article may look daunting, but I think it's pretty easy to understand (it's just long).

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks Ryan. That was helpful. Correct me if I am wrong. HTTP headers can be only sent from the web server to the client browser when a request is made by the client. Is that correct? 

When you say **simulate HTTP headers** what does this mean? What is a character set and how is this used? The reason I ask is I have seen it referenced in PHP as well.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Yes, because the HTTP protocol is stateless (meaning, the connection between client and server is closed after the client receives its response), HTTP headers can only be sent from server-to-client (and vice versa) when the client is making a request. To **simulate HTTP headers** means that instead of using a real HTTP header, you put a <meta> tag on the page that will result in the exact same thing in the browser.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - As for the question about character sets, you really should read the article I posted. It gives a very simple, straightforward, and thorough answer on the subject. That being said, if you're not planning to work with Chinese characters (or any other non-English characters), just put the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` tag on your page and you won't really need to worry about it. However, if you're going to build an international application, you're probably going to have to learn about them, and that article is a great place to start.

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks Ryan. Is there a reason why I would simulate HTTP headers?

Comment: You might need to override the server's default header.  Or write a page for offline use where there are no HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan: Great link. I wish I had read the article 12 years ago before I embarked on a large international CMS implementation.

In simple terms, when the browser receives an HTTP response stream (the web page that was requested), all it sees is a sequence of bytes. Because bytes can mean different characters, depending on the encoding that was used by the server, it is *very* important that the browser uses the encoding specified in the meta tag when interpreting the byte stream. If the server used a different encoding than what it put in the meta tag, you will see gibberish.

Conversely, the HTTP request associated with a web page POST also has an encoding that is provided transparently by the browser, because the server needs to know how to interpret any form data that was sent.